# Nef and effective classes on abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Is there any characterization of rational nef classes that don't come from effective $\mathbb{Q}$-divisors on abelian varieties? Is there any result along the lines of "Any nef $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor is the sum of an effective $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor with a numerically trivial divisor"? A useful observation is that the nef cone coincides with the pseudoeffective cone on an abelian variety.

Comment: I think your statement follows from Lemma 1.1 in Bauer's paper 'On the cone of curves of an abelian variety', since algebraic equivalence coincides with numerical equivalence on an abelian variety.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @J.C.Ottem It seems that algebraic equivalence coincides with numerical equivalence up to torsion for divisors holds for any smooth variety. See this answer and its reference: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15001/algebraic-equivalence-vs-numerical-equivalence-an-example